# Low noise amplifier

Tags: amplifier, measurement

Recently, I got a low noise amplifier (i.e., ZFL-1000LN+ from MiniCircuits, http://194.75.38.69/pdfs/ZFL-1000LN+.pdf) with two wires already soldered in the turrent terminal pins. Today I have been trying to use it, but unfortunately it did not work. I connected the wire soldered in the GND pin to the GND point in my power supply and the other to the possitive connection. I was wondering if is it that the correct way or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your power supply have +V, 0V and a separate ground? If so, you also need to connect 0V to Ground on the power supply.

Comment: Are you familiar with impedance matching?

Comment: "unfortunately it did not work" - what precisely does that mean. If you went to the doctor and said ONLY that you were ill, he'd show you the door to leave.

Comment: it means that I had no output in the oscilloscope, no signal

Comment: Did you have an RF input to it (confirmed with the scope you were using (verifies both input and scope))? What current was the amplifier drawing. What voltage did you measure on the amplifier terminal pins?

Comment: Here's a bench power supply, now what terminals did you use: http://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Lid.jpg - just state the colours to make it easy.

Comment: 1) Check with a multimeter that you have at least 12 V DC between the GND and the supply connection of the LNA. If not: fix this first. 2) Check on the (lab) supply you're using that it draws around 40 - 60 mA. If it does not, it is broken. 3) Apply a 10 mV signal of 1 MHz to the input and connect your scope to the output. You should see the amplified signal.

Comment: @Andyaka I used the red and the one in the middle (between black and red).

Comment: That will be the problem (unless of course the amp is dead too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used the red and the one in the middle (between black and red)

[image]

Use the red and black terminals. If you need to use green (to earth your set-up) then it's normal to connect it to the black terminal.

Comment: This hit me as a newbie too. Pretty bad UI design really, although a common one.

Comment: @pipe It's a matter of convention.

Comment: @pipe: only if you have no clue about what gnd is

Comment: @PlasmaHH There's no reason for the *earth* connection to be positioned in between positive and negative, especially not when bipolar supplies are common enough.

Comment: @pipe - putting the ground between the + and - makes it convenient to tie _either_ output to ground, as necessary.